# Higher-Order Component and accessing child of the wrapped element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

Pretty new to React, and I have this issue where 2 of my components are fairly similar, but different enough to not be the same.

I looked up a way to compose the components and avoid duplications, and with `Mixins` out of the way, I encountered HOC, which I think can be pretty powerful, yet confusing for somebody like me who's not yet familiar with React and its inner workings.

So I have my main component(wrappee) which will then be wrapped. In turn that component renders a child component (in my case a `textarea` for one of the wrappee component, the other one being an `input` field).

One of the reasons why I'd like to use HOC is that I bind event listeners to the text input, and so need to be able to access it from the HOC.

```
    Textarea ---- InputController ---- InputHOC
    Input    ---/
```

In practice I have managed a way to communicate the DOM element back to the HOC, using a callback in `ref`. But I feel it's pretty dirty, as I have to have 2 callbacks:

`InputController`:

```
 return (
  <div>
    {textareaHint}
    <div className='longtext-input-wrapper'>
      {textareaComponent}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

`textareaComponent`

```
return <TextareaAutosize
          ref = {
            (c) => {
              this._input = c
            }
          }
          className={classList}
          minRows={MIN_ROWS}
        />
```

and then in `InputHOC`:

```
 <div className={submitButtonClass}>
    <Button clickHandler={_buttonClickHandler.bind(this)} ref='submitButton'>
      <span className='button-text'>Ok</span>
      <span className='button-icon'>✔</span>
    </Button>
    <InputComponent ref={
        (item) => {
          if (item && !this.input) {
            this.input = item._input
          }
        }
      } 
    />
 </div>
```

And then I can access `this.input` in `componentDidMount`:

```
const inputNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.input)
```

It does really feel hacky, so I was wondering if there was a better way to deal with this?

Thanks a lot for your input

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't look like the HOC pattern to me. The term HOC implies a function that, when called on a component, returns a (higher-order) component that works similarly to the original component, but with additional or changed behaviors. Your `InputHOC` just looks like a regular component that renders other components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jordan is right, this is not using the HOC pattern.  A good example of this pattern can be found here: https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775.  You can think of a HOC as a superclass for the component that it wraps, but it's not actually a class.  A HOC is a function that takes a react component and returns a new one with the desired enhancements.

What you are doing is using `ref` callbacks to link together all of your components and making other components aware of things other than their direct children, which is definitely not recommended.  In your case, I don't see why you shouldn't place everything from `InputHOC` into `InputController`.  Then, define the functions that you want to bind to the input in `TextareaAutosize` in `InputController` and pass them as props.  It would look something like this:

InputController:

```
class InputController extends React.Component {
  handleChange() {
    // Note that 'this' will not be set to the InputController element
    // unless you bind it manually
    doSomething();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button clickHandler={_buttonClickHandler.bind(this)} ref='submitButton'>
        <span className='button-text'>Ok</span>
        <span className='button-icon'>✔</span>
      </Button>
      <div>
        {textareaHint}
        <div className='longtext-input-wrapper'>
          <TextareaAutosize callback={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

TextareaAutosize

```
class TextAreaAutosize extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <textarea onChange={this.props.onChange}>
        Some text value
      </textarea>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, I think I understand what I did wrong, I should pipe the behaviour down the props instead of emitting the DOM element back... Yeah that makes more sense. Thanks a lot